# Push to master only the merged commit, without development history

Tags: git

I have `origin/master` with the main code and my own local `development` branch. When I am done in development, I want to merge the outcome to `master` and push to `origin`.

My local git looks like that:

```
*   5555 (HEAD, origin/master master) merged development, master code v 2
|\
| * 4444 (development) some
| * 3333 feature
| * 2222 added
|/
* 1111 master code v 1
```

When I do `git push` on `master` I would like the `origin/master` to have only commits: `1111`  and `2222`, so it would look like:

```
* 5555 (HEAD, master) merged development, master code v 2
* 1111 master code v 1
```

But when I do `git push origin mainline` then all three commits from development are pushed as well.

**Edit**

- I know I should `merge` or `merge --squash`, My question is only about pushing the "main" commit path, without `development` trash

Comment: You mean you only want commits `1111` and `5555`, is that correct?

Comment: @Cupcake: that's correct. I use rebase and merge daily, I hoped there is some magic flag to say "push only main parent commits" or something similar

Comment: Sounds like you want `git merge --squash`...

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have typos in your question, but it sounds like you just want to have all the work done in `development` merged into `master` as one commit, is that correct? If that is the case, then you can simply squash the commits on your `development` branch into one commit, then merge them into `master`:

```
git checkout development
git rebase -i HEAD~3

# After done squashing
git checkout master
git merge development
git push origin master
```

Or, as [@akaRem suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22566632/456814), you can simply do a soft or mixed reset on the `development` branch and re-commit all the changes as one commit:

```
git checkout development
git reset --soft 1111
git commit
git checkout master
git merge development
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

Interactive rebase is an overkill in this simple case. I find `git reset --soft` a simpler and faster solution:

```
git reset --soft 1111
```

All your changes from 2222, 3333, 4444 are uncomitted now, but staged and will be added to commit. Verify if everything is correct and then

```
git commit -m "<Insert your meaningful commit message here>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to do `git --reset ...`, then commit changes in one commit and push it to origin

Answer (score 1):

In your development branch do `git rebase -i 2222`. Your editor will open with content like:

```
pick 2222 added
pick 3333 feature
pick 4444 (development) some
```

Change the last two lines to start with 'f' for *fixup*:

```
pick 2222 added
f 3333 feature
f 4444 (development) some
```

Save and exit the editor. Look at your log now:

```
$ git log --oneline
pick 2345 added
pick 1111 master code v 1
```

The lastest commit is now a combination of the three changes in your branch. You can now proceed to cherry-pick that change into master:

```
git checkout master && git cherry-pick 2345
```

or you can rebase master *into* your branch and then merge back into master:

```
git rebase master && git checkout master && git merge development
```

The end result will be much the same.

If you use a shared repository model, this workflow will result in your *local* development branch being divergent from your remote development branch. You can reset your local development branch after making these changes, or use a temporary branch to do the rebase. (If you intend to keep the branch around at all.)